# 'Seen as' or 'seeing as'

Tags: grammar, past-participles, present-participles

Look at these examples:

> You should clean the milk **seen as** you spilt it.
>   You should clean the milk **seeing as** you spilt it.

Which one is correct, and how is it grammatically defined/termed?

Answer (score 13):

*Seeing as* is the generally accepted form; I don't recall ever hearing anyone say *seen as* (though it's possible I just didn't notice).

Grammatically speaking, *seeing as* is a conjunction; it fills the same function here as *because*. The Oxford English Dictionary defines it this way:

> ***seeing that***, hence ellipt. ***seeing***: considering the fact that; inasmuch as; since, because. Also (*colloq.*) with *as (how)*.

Its history goes at least as far back as 1504:

> 1504 W. Barons in *Paston Lett. & Papers* (2004) II. 501, I wol‥exhorte you to take it as‥paciently as ye can, seeyng that we al be mortal and borne to dey.

Comment: +1, agreed. "Seen as" is a classic eggcorn.

Comment: *Seen as* in this context could be seen as an eggcorn, but *seen as* is an idiom by itself.